# Piano finger numbers for the attached measure

Tags: piano, fingering

I was wondering if anyone could add finger numbers above each note on the measure below. I can't really seem to find a way to play the whole thing and still manage play it in legato (notice the slurs above notes).

[image]

[complete music sheet](https://musescore.com/user/32517/scores/1559271)

Comment: You know you have to use the pedal to be able to play this, don't you?

Comment: @TimH legato means playing notes in such a way that they slightly overlap each other so it becomes rather continuous and smooth. and the key to such a way is puzzling out right fingering. for more information you can check this link out.(look at what user15493's wrriten) https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4504/what-does-an-arc-mean-above-the-notes-in-a-piano-sheet-music-how-do-i-play-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fingering would be the same regardless of key signature for this. 
RH: 421, 421, 51, 51, 421, 532, 15, 15
LH: (51)21, 521, 51, 51, 521, 521, 51, 51

The trick in the RH is changing the pattern on the last F chord so you can get down to the E.
The trick in the LH to get that low note is to cross over the 2nd finger to get up the octave.